# Фильтрация логов samba, или вывод конкретной строки в файл лога samba

Tags: linux, samba, rsyslog

Веду аудит действий пользователей в samba. Логи пишутся в файл `/var/log/samba/audit.log`, во много строк, например:

```
smbd_audit: 0066\domainuser|shara|create_file|ok|0x100080|dir|open|/srv/data/shara/UUU/
smbd_audit: 0066\domainuser|shara|create_file|ok|0x100080|dir|create|/srv/data/shara/UUU/
```

Пишет все строки, а нужно записать только строку с опцией `|create|`, а с опцией `|open|` или другими отбросить.
Сделал такой конфиг в файле `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
if $syslogfacility == 'local6.notice' and $msg isequal 'create'  then /var/log/audit.log
```

Как все строки писались так и пишутся. Что я делаю не так?

OC Linux CentOS 7, SAMBA 4.9.1, ad win2k8!

Answer (score 1):

Свойство сообщения "$msg" в rsyslog обозначает всё сообщение в целом. Как результат, приведённое сравнение срабатывать не будет. Согласно [документации](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/filters.html#compare-operations) предлагаю использовать оператор "contains".